# TabularData DataFrame Remove Duplicate Rows

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
import TabularData 

var demoFrame = DataFrame()
let nameColumn = Column(name: "Name", contents: ["Alex", "John", "Alex"])

demoFrame.append(column: nameColumn)
print(demoFrame)
```

As you can see I have "Alex" as a duplicated name.

How can I create a DataFrame without the duplicates. You can run this on a Swift Playground.

Comment: Why not filter the array before passing it to the `contents` parameter?

Comment: It is part of a CSV file which is loaded and the people in charge did not remove the duplicates.

Comment: You misunderstand me. Just filter the array in your code just before passing it to the `contents` parameter.

Comment: The example I gave was just for simplicity. The actual data is loaded from an array using var dataFrame = try DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: fileURL, options: options)

Comment: Ok then filter the `options` array before you pass it to the `options` parameter.

Comment: What would op be filtering on?